# All Yii2 controller not allow action without login or guest must need login

Tags: yii2

I'm using Yii2 Advance application and i am new in yii2 so how make

> all yii2 controller not allow action without login or guest must me login

i mean controllers can not open without login if user not login so redirect in login page this not for one controller i need many controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add below code in common/main.php after components part.

```
'as beforeRequest' => [  //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
        'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                'allow' => true,
            ],
            [
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Wow bhai thanks you vijay bhai you are rock in yii2 :)

Comment: I think you might get a readyment Widget online to acieve this.

Comment: scrolling pagination concept you know like when we scroll down automatically load more product or category ?? if yes then how use in yii2 ??

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-scroll-pager/

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-infinite-scroll/

this will help you

Comment: Great Solution, Its really helpful

Comment: Thanks i was about to create rules and roles and based on it i have decided to check if the given user has permission or not .. Saved lots of time thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create a super controller for this :

```
class Controller extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => false,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

And of course all your controllers should extend this one.

Read more about [Access Control Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try write in index.php in your backed public directory
No need to repeat in controllers

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/../../config/web.php';
$config["controllerNamespace"]='app\controllers\backend';
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    $request_headers = apache_request_headers();
    $srv=$request_headers['Host'];
    header("Location: https://".$srv);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use RBAC Manager for Yii 2 you can Easy to manage authorization of user.
https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could inherit from the yii Controller class where you can override the [beforeAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction()-detail) method and in that function you can redirect the user if there is no active logged in session.
Make sure that all of the other controllers what you are using inherited from your new controller class.

**EDIT:**

In the SuperController beforeAction you can check if the current call is your site/index, if not then redirect to there like:

```
if($action->controller != "site" && $action->id != "index" ) {
  $this->goHome();
}
```

Make sure that the goHome() take you to your site/index.

And you can split your Site actionIndex() method to an authenticated or not part like:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute('site/login'));
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: bro i am super controller  like SuperController.php  and make  beforeAction() method but how redirect sitecontroller Login Method i will try it Yii::$app->runaction('SiteController/Login'); but not working