# How to install Jquery UI in YII2 advance template?

Tags: yii2

I work on YII project (advanced) and want to use JUI Extension for Yii 2
but getting this kind of error

**Yii soft/yii2-jui 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/j query- Ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.**

Comment: Try to add `"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"` to the require section of your composer.json file.

Comment: First take a a backup of your project.
 Try to update your composer.  After updating it try to installl Jquery Ui again

Comment: @GAMITG this alredy try it but same error getting again and again

Comment: @vijaynathji  composer update used for composer i am right ??

Comment: yes by updating your composer you will able to install extension.

Comment: @vijaynathji ==> http://i.stack.imgur.com/gxPzI.png

Comment: I am not able to see scrrenshot.. its showing blank image

Comment: @vijaynathji ==> http://myshorter.tk/123/error.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

If you want to install the JUI extension for Yii2, you should do the following steps:

Run the following composer command:

```
php composer.phar require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

Run
`php composer.phar update`

Run

`php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui`

Comment: AppAsset.php code  ==>  <?php


namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;


class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/frontend/';
    public $css = [
     'css/style.css',
        'css/bootstrap.css',
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800',
     
    ];
    
    public $js = [
    ]; 
    
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',     
     'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
     'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
     
    ];
     public $jsOptions =[ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ];
}

Comment: gussa mat karo bhai abhi chal raha hey sliding iske liye aap ka bahut bada aabharaaaaaa ;) thanks you  abhi bhi mere dimag me ek question hey  "public $jsOptions =[ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ];"  ye add kiya tab chal ne laga toh iska thoda description do bhai

Comment: hi...Remove unneccesary comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163542/all-yii2-controller-not-allow-action-without-login-or-guest-must-need-login  iska koi solution hey ???

Comment: yes... it is quite same as yii2.... Unfortunately i do not know coding in Laravel... I also want to learn.. :(

Comment: i am not quite yii2 ;) but my next project come in laravel so i have 15 days for preparation that why ask you :)

Comment: vijay bhai mujhe help chahiye   wordpress site ko multilanguage convert used karna hey toh kya karna hoga aur konsa aacha plugin hey ???

Comment: check this https://wpml.org/ 
and 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/

Comment: free ho vesa bolo na :(

Comment: polylanguage choose kiya hey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117388/discussion-between-vijay-nathji-and-hothi-jimit).